# Is there a way to change displayed format of integeres in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, there is an option to change the display format of floats using `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}.format`. However, I couldn't find any analogous option specifically for integers. And I'm referring not to specific settings for a single dataframe, but rather to global settings.

And what I need it for is to basically convert something like '123456789' to '123,456,789'.

If there are any alternative methods or solutions for formatting integers in pandas, I'll be glad to hear it. Thank you.